# to have on the payroll

Tags: meaning

> Other statistics come from
>   a separate survey of about 160,000 business establishments that employ over
>   40 million workers. When you read a headline that says the economy created a
>   certain number of jobs last month, that statistic is the change in the number of
>   workers that businesses report *having on their payrolls*.

Do I understand it correctly that businesses report **the number** of employees that they keep on the staff ? I am not sure whether they report the number or the change in the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, *on the payroll* is an expression often used in business and economics to describe how many employees a company has hired. For example, if I have a small business with 10 employees, I might say:

> My business has ten workers on the payroll.

You've also interpreted the phrase "the change in the number of workers that businesses report having on their payrolls" correctly. For example, if I had ten workers in 2014, but my business is expanding, so I hire two more in 2015, then my payroll was expanded by 20%.

However, the metric discussed in your quote isn't so much concerned with a single business; rather, it analyzes data from 160,000 businesses combined. So, I might hire two new workers, but, if these workers had been working somewhere else, the net gain would be zero, because, even though I have two more workers, two other businesses might have one less worker.

Comment: You are right about the zero net gain. Initially, I haven't thought of this idea. This is your logical conclusion from what is quoted above. So, to make sure that I've understood you correctly, they report the changes in the number according to their payroll, not the number itself, right?

Comment: I believe they add up the number of people employed by the 160,000 businesses, and then report the change. For example, if those 160,000 business had 400,000 employees in May, and 420,000 employees in June, a report might say "there were 20,000 new jobs in June," or "the number of new jobs went up 5% in June." Your quote is emphasizing that those 20,000 "new" jobs could be 20,000 new jobs and no loss of old jobs, or 30,000 new jobs minus 10,000 jobs that went away, and the number would be reported the same either way (probably because it would be too hard to count them any other way).

Answer (score 1):

"To have on payroll" basically just means "to routinely pay." In a majority of cases, an "employee on payroll" is redundant, and said only to reinforce the fact that we aren't talking about contract workers.

So no, I'd say it sounds like the business reports the *change*, and not the actual number. The idea is that you want to know how many jobs created (the new number of jobs minus the old number) to know the growth rate of the economy.

"We hired three hundred employees last month" would tell you more about the growth rate than simply knowing the total number they have. Of course, this particular quote is talking about 160,000 businesses, but the same thing applies.

Comment: *In a majority of cases, an "employee on payroll" is redundant*. What about workers [employees] paid off the books? :) I mean illegal immigrants, particularly, this is the case for USA.

Comment: @Humbulani Ha, that's not a bad point. Although the phrase "on payroll" doesn't *really* exclude those sorts of arrangements, in a majority of cases. Although, of course, it really depends on context. "On the payroll" is often meant figuratively, especially when it comes to less-than-legal dealings.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is the difference between "permanent/regular" employees which are paid by the company and are so on the payroll, and contractors (and "employees" provided by third party companies such as cleaners) who will be "off-payroll" as they will be paid via different manners (such as invoices).

Temporary employees *may* also be excluded from the "on payroll" figures (especially if they are used for less than a month) as they may be paid "cash in hand/self-declare tax" but this may vary depending on location (in the UK, you would still have to put them on the payroll).